# What is the effect of different ways to adding liquid materials into a mixing tank?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering

I am working with body wash products and there is a problem happening with the mixing process.
I use a 5000-liter tank to mix all the liquid materials including water, surfactant and preservatives. When I use a vacuum pump to add liquid materials from the bottom of tank, the content of preservative is A (g/100g). However, when I add them throug hthe top of tank, the content of preservative decreases. 
I am really confused because everything (amount of materials, equipment, machines) used in 2 ways is the same. And I have no idea why the content decreases.
Please share your opinion. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any stirring of the tank or do the contents just get to settle?

Comment: Where are your samples being taken from?  This sounds like a non-homogenous mixture and your samples will vary as a result.

Comment: @SolarMike: Yes, we keep stirring the solution during adding phenoxyethanol.

Comment: @GlenH7: we took 3 samples from the top, the middle and the bottom of tank. And the contents of phenoxyethanol of those 3 samples is almost the same.

Comment: can you provide a sketch of your setup with the tank, the pump and the inlets (top and bottom)?

Comment: Please describe how you are measuring the additive put into the tank.  If you are timing the addition, only a positive displacement pump would have the same flow rate into the tank at the top as at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your **additives are in suspension** not solution. Like a fruit juice drink. You take orange  powder stir it and it makes a nice drink. Leave it several hours without drinking it and you will return to a glass of water with orange stuff at the bottom. If the solution is not continually stirred the additives will sink to the bottom.

Comment: we took 3 samples from the top, the middle and the bottom of tank. And the contents of phenoxyethanol of those 3 samples is almost the same. I do not think that the solution is not homogenized.

Comment: Now I am confused your problem was that there was more at the bottom than the top but now you say they are the same?

Comment: Hi, let me clear about that. First, I add all the materials including phenoxyethanol to the tank through a valve at the bottom, and I took 3 samples. And then, I change the way, add all materials through a valve at the top of tank and I also took 3 samples. I measured all 6 samples. The results showed that with 2 different ways of adding ingredients, the content of phenoxyethanol was different. To be more specific, the content of samples in the first way is higher than that in the second way. My English is not so good. I hope you are clear now

Comment: I suppose you have checked that the missing phenoxyethanol when added at the top is not forming an oily top layer. I presume your tank has a majority water mix and  phenoxyethanol  is only QUOTE slightly soluble in water. Possibly your are getting a better mix when adding from the bottom where it is not so easily able to seperate. Also it can degrade when it is exposed to oxygen https://memim.com/phenoxyethanol.html